# How to create a test account (to do automated tests) for Amazon FPS?

Tags: amazon-fps

I'm kinda lost here at http://payments-sandbox.amazon.com/

I want to set up the test user for Amazon FPS which will be used by my [Behat](http://behat.org)-based web acceptance tests.
The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonFPS/latest/SandboxLanding/index.html) states that it's possible. However, as Amazon constantly requires you to re-authorize yourself almost on every page change, I don't understand where the page to create a test account is.

So, does anyone have a personal experience with setting up a test account to autotest the application which uses FPS for purchases? How it's done and where? I prefer to not register a completely imaginary person along with fake SSN and phone number just for test suite. Or I'm out of luck here?

Comment: I did this a while ago and can't recall the exact steps (sorry) but I'm fairly certain that I ended up on the phone with support which got me going. https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/contactusclick2call